# Show the values in one row with same id in sql

Tags: mysql

I have Three tables and I join the table and retrieve all the values in this query

sql query:

```
 SELECT wp_term_relationships.object_id, wp_posts.post_title,                                        
 wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value
 FROM `wp_posts` , wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships
 WHERE (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
 AND (wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id)  
 AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =33
```

Its Show Table structure is this

```
object_id     post_title          meta_key           meta_value
 302       CHICKEN CHOW MEIN     post_image           url1
 302        CHICKEN CHOW MEIN      price              6.95
```

I want Show the OBject Id in one and merge the two rows in one column i want like this

```
object_id     post_title      meta_value(price)     meta_value(post_image)
302       CHICKEN CHOW MEIN         6.95                url1
```

Comment: Do you really need this to work on all three tagged RDBMSs? I expect this is only MySQL (looks like a WordPress db).

Comment: yes I want merge the same id and get in one row..In sql query itself ..

Comment: yes its wordpress db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join to `wp_postmeta` twice, using more usual join syntax

```
SELECT rel.object_id, p.post_title,
       meta_price.meta_key, meta_price.meta_value,
       meta_image.meta_key, meta_image.meta_value
FROM `wp_posts` p
    inner join wp_postmeta meta_price on meta_price.post_id = p.ID
    inner join wp_postmeta meta_image on meta_image.post_id = p.ID
    inner join wp_term_relationships rel on rel.objet_id = p.ID
WHERE rel.term_taxonomy_id = 33
    and meta_price.meta_key = 'price'
    and meta_image.meta_key = 'post_image'
```

(Syntax not checked – no access to a WordPress db here – and you'll need to change the selected columns slightly.)

Comment: This assumes that a price and image exists for every post_title

Comment: @Strawberry It does. Switch from `inner` to `left outer` for the joins if not always the case.

Comment: thanq for u r solution.there is small error on object  its like spell mistake....

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd simply stick with your existing query, and handle the pivot in the application code, so.

```
*PHP goes here*

$query = "

 SELECT r.object_id
      , p.post_title
      , m.meta_key
      , m.meta_value
   FROM wp_posts p
   JOIN wp_postmeta m
     ON m.post_id = p.ID 
   JOIN wp_term_relationships r
     ON r.object_id = m.post_id
  WHERE r.term_taxonomy_id = 33
  ORDER 
     BY post_title
      , meta_key;

";

*More PHP goes here*
```

Answer (score -1):

Syntax not checked, but something like this?

```
SELECT object_id, post_title, max(meta_key_price) as key_price, max(meta_key_image) as key_image FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        wp_term_relationships.object_id,
        wp_posts.post_title,                                        
        case meta_key when 'price' then meta_value else null end as meta_key_price,
        case meta_key when 'post_image' then meta_value else null end as meta_key_image
    FROM `wp_posts` , wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships
    WHERE (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
        AND (wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id)  
        AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =33
) as t group by object_id
```

Comment: unknown column error showing please check the joins.

Comment: if you could be more specific about the error please. All I did was add 2 case statements, and wrap in a group by. You could try being specific about location of your `meta_key` and `meta_value` by specifying the tables... `wp_postmeta.meta_key`, `wp_postmeta.meta_value`

Comment: @Gravy You forgot to include some kind of aggregating function (MAX is a popular choice)

Comment: @Strawberry - Good spot

Comment: because in the group by, I still had the inner sql table names, rather than having the column names from within t. Can't test as I dont do wordpress.